# Prevent IFRAME from automatically reloading in iOS Web App

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iframe

I've got a web application that runs on an iPad mini. The icon for it has been added to the desktop so that it can run without the browser UI elements. There is a point in the application in which I must display content from another web site within an IFRAME. The other website attempts to set the top level URL. To get around this I've had to use the SANDBOX attribute on the IFRAME so that the other website opens in a dialog type window.

```
            <iframe id="testIframe" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" seamless ></iframe>
```

The content displays as expected. The problem occurs when someone presses DONE button to close the IFRAME dialog. The UI returns to my page and the state of the page is restored automatically. Unfortunately this includes the state of the IFRAME. As soon as the UI returns to my page the IFRAME causes the dialog to open again. This leaves the application in a loop where someone can only view the IFRAME content from thereon.

Is there someway to prevent this behaviour?

(note: I've tested this with an iPad Pro with the same firmware number and see entirely different behaviour for the same HTML)

I've been able to replicate the behaviour in the below. The actual URL that I attempt to load is omitted for confidentiality.

JavaScript:

```js
        function go() {
            var address = document.getElementById('addressTextbox').value;
            console.log(address)
            var iframe = document.getElementById('testIframe');
            iframe.src = address;
            console.log(iframe.src);
        }

        function preventReload() { 
            var iframe = document.getElementById('testIframe');
            iframe.src = '';
            console.debug('set iframe src = nothing');
        }


        if (window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type == window.performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD) {
            preventReload();
        }

        

        window.onbeforeunload=preventReload;
        window.onload=preventReload;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Guest Control">
    <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">

    <!--PWA-ish attributes-->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./jxi.png">
    <title>IFRAME test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        html, body { 
            background-color: #F080A0;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
        iframe {
            width:100%;
            
        }

        #rootVisual {
            background-color: #808080;
            position:absolute;
            left:0px;
            right:0px;
            top:0px;        
            bottom:0px;           
        }

        #addressArea {
            background-clip: #8080FF;
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            right:0px;
            height:30px;
           
        }

        #testIframe { 
            position:absolute;
            top:0x;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            height:100%;
            bottom:0;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="go.js"></script>
    <script>
    
    

    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="rootVisual">
            <iframe id="testIframe" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" seamless ></iframe>
        <div id="addressArea">
            <input type="text" id="addressTextbox" value="">
            <button id="goButton" onclick="go()" >Go</button>
            <button id="gogoButton" onclick="go();go()">Gogo</button>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```